# how to add values in empty column in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have problem while adding value to `df['data2']` column.

[image]

But I want this output in `df['data2']` column:

[image]

Last value is copied in each row of `df['data2']` column.Please suggest me a way to add value to each index of `df['data2']` while using for loop?

Comment: You need to iterate over each row. `df['data2'][i] = val`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You ovewrite the whole `df['date2']` every loop. Try instead:

```
df['date2']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'])+pd.to_timedelta(df['num'].astype(np.int),'D')
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you could do it this Pandas way:

```
df['date2'] = df['date'] + pd.to_timedelta(df['num'].astype(str) + ' day')
```